# Renaming external 3rd party library classes in my library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add add 3rd part library to my library (which will be used by other developers), so if I have for example this class `SBJson` do I prefix it with my two letter prefix to be `EXSBJson` also I saw somewhere somebody is using underscore `EX_SBJson`. What is the naming convention/style in this case?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general convention, but we have used the following approaches:

1. Use the same prefix as the library (so if we develop XYFunctionality, we would name it XYSBJson). A lot of source projects use this approach (e.g. Dropbox)
2. Talk to other devs, if possible. In most cases, it is enough to distribute the library separately from 3rd party libs (so we ship a .a binary file and a working source project of the 3rd party library so other devs can use it). This also allows other devs to upgrade the 3rd party library to get bugfixes as long as there aren't breaking API changes.

Btw. much of what SBJson does can also be done using NSJsonSerialization which comes with iOS 5+

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using NSJsonSerialization but used SBJson as an example.